# Integral of Brownian motion

Tags: brownian-motion

Is there any formula for the following integral ?

> $$\int_0^t W_t^n\; \mathrm{d}W_t $$

For $n=1$ the answer is known. What about $n=2,3,\ldots$?

Comment: Have you tried Ito's lemma?

Comment: Yes, but no result

Answer (score 1):

Using Ito's lemma with $f(x):=x^{n+1}$,
$$
W_t^{n+1}=(n+1)\int_0^t W_s^n\,dW_s+\frac{(n+1)n}{2}\int_0^t W_s^{n-1}\,ds.
$$
Therefore,
$$
\int_0^t W_s^n\,dW_s=\frac{W_t^{n+1}}{n+1}-\frac{n}{2}\int_0^t W_s^{n-1}\,ds.
$$